# Using the OnInit event in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have contentpage overriding the OnInit event of a masterpage. The override works fine, until I put a custom user control on the page: in this case the OnInit event does not fire for the contentpage (no overrides are used in the user control)

What are the possible causes/solutions for this? (I use the OnInit event to create dynamic controls)

---

**Edit:**

now i tried this in the content page:

(The OnPreInit part runs, but Masters_Init does not get called...)

```
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.Master.Init += new EventHandler(Masters_Init);
    }

    void Masters_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
    //code 
    }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Are you calling the base.OnInit?

```
public override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
  // code before base oninit
  base.OnInit(e);
  // code after base oninit
}
```

**Update**

```
public class Page1 : Page
{
  public Page1 : base() {
    PreInit += Page_PreInit;
  }
  void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Master.Init += Master_Init;
  }
  void Master_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    //code
  }
}
```

Also as mentioned in the comments I would recommend not overriding the events if you don't have to, but if you must be sure to call the base.  so in your edit above it should be

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
  base.OnPreInit(e);
  base.Master.Init += new EventHandler(Masters_Init);
}
```

Comment: sure, but the event is not firing: so it does not matter anyway

Comment: Can you just subscribe to the Init event of the masterpage instead of override OnInit?

Comment: try subscribing to you event in the constuctor of the page.  BTW if you override any methods always call the base.  and don't override if you don't have to.

Comment: public Page1 {
    Master.Init += Masters_Init;
  }

throws:
NullReferenceException

Comment: try adding the call to base() in the constructor.

Comment: correction http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.master.aspx states that "The contents of a master page are not available until after the PreInit event has been raised"

Comment: Does your master page have any code-behind? does this work if you don't have the usercontrol added?

Comment: yes it works without the user control and my masterpage does NOT have any related code, just some events for standard controls and a simple Page_Load.

Comment: I have to ask then whats in your usercontrol?

Comment: In the user control I only handle events of standard controls (inside the control) and have 2 public methods (designed to be called on init & load from the page containing the control)... I removed almost everything from the control and this still did not work :S

Comment: Can you provide some code. or reproduce the issue in a small code sample that you can append to the question so that I can try to reproduce the issue locally?

Comment: I just tested it with an empty usercontrol and it works... it really must be something in this particular control

Comment: Now i removed everything from codebehind (and the events from the markup) in the user control and it still happens

Comment: I sounds like there is something else going on here.  Can you repro it in a blank project?

Comment: got it: I think VS did put in another scriptmanager automatically into some obscure place. The compiler reported no error or warning, but things where screwed up. problem solved by removing second scriptmanager... Thanks for your time!